Does each partition file contain all columns after Spark DataFrameWriter.partitionBy?
In a Spark data pipeline, I want to rely on mapPartitions to run some computations. I prepare some data and want to store it in partitions using DataFrameWriter.partitionBy.
Is it guaranteed that each of the partitions contain all columns? Given Parquet's columnar nature, I am a bit confused on whether I can trust that each Parquet file will actually contain full column set or not. It seems to be the case for a small dataset, but can I rely on it to be the case?

When you write using Dataframe.partitionBy(c1, c2).write.parquet(), the individual parquet file will not contain c1 and c2. That information is put in the directory structure.
E.g.
>>>
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[
...         ('TX', 'dallas',  1000),
...         ('TX', 'austin',  2000),
...         ('FL', 'miami',   1000),
...         ('FL', 'orlando', 2000),
...     ], schema='state: string, city: string, sales: int'
... )
>>> df.show()
+-----+-------+-----+
|state|   city|sales|
+-----+-------+-----+
|   TX| dallas| 1000|
|   TX| austin| 2000|
|   FL|  miami| 1000|
|   FL|orlando| 2000|
+-----+-------+-----+

>>> df = df.repartition(1)
>>> df.write.parquet('/tmp/unpartitioned')
>>> df.write.partitionBy('state').parquet('/tmp/partitioned')
>>> # above is same as following:
>>> # df.write.partitionBy('state').format("parquet").save('/tmp/partitioned')
>>> 

Will produce this:
$ cd /tmp
$ tree /tmp/unpartitioned/
unpartitioned/
├── part-00000-0950db84-79c8-4e3e-9b6a-732ada962185-c000.snappy.parquet
└── _SUCCESS

0 directories, 2 files
$ parquet-tools show /tmp/unpartitioned/part-00000-0950db84-79c8-4e3e-9b6a-732ada962185-c000.snappy.parquet 
+---------+---------+---------+
| state   | city    |   sales |
|---------+---------+---------|
| TX      | dallas  |    1000 |
| TX      | austin  |    2000 |
| FL      | miami   |    1000 |
| FL      | orlando |    2000 |
+---------+---------+---------+
$ 

and the partitioned parquet files don't contain the column that we partitionBy():
$ tree /tmp/partitioned/
partitioned/
├── state=FL
│   └── part-00000-d67b2e8c-846c-44ff-a1da-d1dae3a072f5.c000.snappy.parquet
├── state=TX
│   └── part-00000-d67b2e8c-846c-44ff-a1da-d1dae3a072f5.c000.snappy.parquet
└── _SUCCESS

2 directories, 3 files
$ 
$ parquet-tools show /tmp/partitioned/state\=TX/part-00000-d67b2e8c-846c-44ff-a1da-d1dae3a072f5.c000.snappy.parquet 
+--------+---------+
| city   |   sales |
|--------+---------|
| dallas |    1000 |
| austin |    2000 |
+--------+---------+
$ parquet-tools show /tmp/partitioned/state\=FL/part-00000-d67b2e8c-846c-44ff-a1da-d1dae3a072f5.c000.snappy.parquet 
+---------+---------+
| city    |   sales |
|---------+---------|
| miami   |    1000 |
| orlando |    2000 |
+---------+---------+
$ 

So while reading the resulting parquet file you must read /tmp/partitioned and not individual parquet files because the state column is now part of the path (state=FL).

put simply, yes.  In fact it can be an issue from a schema evaluation perspective, i.e. you write a,b,c then later append a,b,c,d,e.  If you do not enable mergeSchema and the partitions with a,b,c are read first it can lead to unpredictability on the available columns.  This stack has a tonne of info on it.
If you can use delta it will offer a more robust way of adding columns (or renaming etc. in later versions), reading files (orders of magnitudes faster as the list of 'chunks' are stored in the transaction log - no directory scanning required) and the ability to modify contents with change feeds etc.

I am a bit confused, you say "yes" as in "It is guaranteed that every partition contains all columns", but the depth of your answer suggests otherwise?

for every file written to from a dataframe it will contain every column.  Those files are immutable, append to it and you can have different columns added, the previous ones haven't changed.   I'd suggest reading that link
